# How to check references during build

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, tfsbuild

I'm looking for a way to check if all projects in solution have references from "right" path.

Let's say, that references can by only:

- project references
- from ....\Lib\
- from ....\Lib2\

any other path is not allowed.

I would like to have this validation during build on TFS or (and) as a check-in rule. Is there a way how to do it?

I would probably be able to write Visual Studio extension an dig into EnvDTE object. But this is backup plan.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22289610/how-can-i-prevent-bad-project-references/22295260

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a custom activity in your build definition template.
2. Custom activity searches for all .CSPROJ (include other project types if needed).
   example:

> Directory.GetFiles(ROOTPATH, "*.csproj", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

1. Search the .CSPROJ file using XPATH query to find the HintPath nodes:

   ```
       XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
       xmlDoc.Load(nameofcsprojfile);

       //Find the current namespace from the XMLDOC and add it to XMLNMManager
       XmlNamespaceManager xnManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
       xnManager.AddNamespace("nm", xmlDoc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);

       //find the nodes based on the following XPATH query
       XmlNode xmlRoot = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
       XmlNodeList xmlProperty = xmlRoot.SelectNodes("//nm:ItemGroup/Reference[@Include]", xnManager);
   ```
2. Go through each of the Reference node and get the HintPath property and make sure that it contain (lib or lib2).
3. If it does not contain, then error out the activity. You can write the following code within the activity to error out the build.

> context.TrackBuildError("fix the reference issues!!!");

Comment: Thank you, finding *.CSPROJ and parse them like xml looks like easiest solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a way to enforce this via static analysis (which seems to be what you want).

However, by having a CI build setup it achieves the same thing in practice.  If people reference things in \bin\debug (which is the typical problem), the CI build won't find them as it directs the binaries to a different directory, the CI Build will fail, and developers will be forced to use proper references to lib.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I already have. But I'm looking for something that will prevent broken build.

Comment: I didn't mention that, but I'm using git as a source control in TFS2013. In this case, Gated builds are not supported.